# Switch stylesheets and using cookies to remember

Tags: javascript, css, cookies, switch-statement, stylesheet

I want to keep my style using cookies when user enter to my website
I have new.css and default.css
I already made buttons what switch those styles using javascript.
I am beginner so I looked on this tutorial: 
http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Change-Style-Sheet-Using-Tutorial-CSS-Swap-Stylesheet
But now I don't know how to program cookies and expiration time. Can you help me? Thank you.

-Sorry for my bad English.
And I know there are many questions about it but as a beginner I don't understand those advanced questions.

Comment: Mozilla Developer Network has great resources on JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. Try this page on JavaScript cookie handling. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it.

Comment: But could you please help me with coding the cookie?

Comment: Hi @Jirkua, try to break your problem into pieces and handle them one by one. `Coding the cookie` is not a one-line solution in your case.